# Restrict file Size when using freopen()

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-files

In my project, I am redirecting the `NSlog` Data to file by using code

```
freopen([FilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

We got a issue that if we keep on writing the data file size may be increased hugely, We want to restrict the data. Lets say after the file size reached 2MB i want to clear the old data and write the new data.
 How can we do it, How can we check the file size in run time.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the `attributesOfItemAtPath:` method of [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&err];
NSNumber *fileSize           = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];

if(//Check whether the size is above 2 MB)
{
   //Remove old content by either removing file or clearing it
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&err];
}
else
{
   //Add data
   freopen([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```